# Java Package Hierarchy: Middle Level Cannot Find Lower Level Despite Import Statement

Tags: java, package, hierarchy

I have defined a data structure that uses another, lower-level data structure, which I also defined.  For tidiness, I want each data structure to have its own directory and package name.  Suppose the higher-level data structure's package is called **packageA** and the lower-level **packageB**.  Then, I want to use the data structure defined in **packageA** in a program-say, **Program**.  So I have a directory structure like this:

```
Program
 |- Program.java
 |- packageA
     |- ClassA.java
     |- packageB
         |- ClassB.java
```

**ClassB.java** has at the top

```
package packageB;
```

**ClassA.java** has at the top

```
package packageA;
import packageB.ClassB;
```

And then **Program.java** has
`import packageA;`
and refers to ClassA in its code.

When I try to compile at the top level with `javac *.java`, I get the error that package **packageB** does not exist.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I accomplish this simple goal?  Thank you.

Comment: Imports are not relative. Irrespective of where you are in the same package hierarchy, you need to make absolute imports.

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement in `ClassA.java` is wrong. The import statement for a type has to be its canonical name. Here's what [JLS 7.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-7.html#jls-SingleTypeImportDeclaration) says:

> **7.5.1. Single-Type-Import Declarations**
>
> A single-type-import declaration imports a single type by giving its canonical name, making it available under a simple name in the module, class, and interface declarations of the compilation unit in which the single-type-import declaration appears.
>
> The TypeName must be the canonical name of a class type, interface type, enum type, or annotation type ([§6.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7)).

And the relevant definition for canonical name in section 6.7 is

> The fully qualified name of a named package that is a subpackage of another named package consists of the fully qualified name of the containing package, followed by ".", followed by the simple (member) name of the subpackage.

This does not make it possible to use relative package names to import. Your import statement must be

```
import packageA.packageB.ClassB;
```

And the package declaration in `ClassB.java` itself must be

```
package packageA.packageB;
```

I'm assuming that `Program` is not a package;

Comment: Thank you so much!  Your assumption is correct.  I had misunderstood packages to have greater independence and portability than they do.  I had expected that I could develop packageB separately somewhere and then simply copy its directory as a subdirectory in some project that would use it—but you cannot do this without going through and changing the package name to match the new directory setting.  Thanks!